# Splitting/Chunking Ogg Vorbis File

Tags: c#, ogg, vorbis

Is there any easy way to chunk an Ogg Vorbis File so that I am able to transcode the chunks? Documentation is so sparse and libogg seams overkill for me because it would be a pain to incorporate in a C# project. Is there a simple methodology of just looking for some segment delimiters in Hex and splitting it out that way?